# How do I make a website respond to whether user has a specific certificate installed?

Tags: javascript, php, ssl-certificate

I have a PHP/JS website which I want to appear slightly differently to users who have a specific certificate installed on their computer. The certificate is *always* the exact same for all these users, so I just need to be able to detect if the user has the certificate (based on parameters like "CN" or the certificate's name, I suppose?), and then act on it, either in PHP or JS.

I don't need to be able to create the certificate for the user or anything - the users in question will be getting the certificate from elsewhere. So is there a simple solution for detecting and responding based on the presence / absence of the certificate?

(As you can maybe tell, I have no prior experience working with certificates, so let me know if I'm misunderstanding something basic.)

Comment: No client is going to send any certificates on its own, the server would have to explicitly request that.

Comment: I assume you're talking about SSL/TLS certificates? Do you have control over the domain to which the specific certificate is connected?

Comment: Users do not typically install certificates on their local machines to access remote content. What is your actual goal?

Comment: @Jay Blanchard - This is not a typical use scenario: I'm developing a corporate website where all employees can be expected to have the corporation certificate installed on their machines.

Comment: @04FS - I'm fine with having the server request the certificate. This is what I'm trying to figure out how to do.

Comment: @KIKO Software - I control the domain on which the website is hosted, and I'm trying to make the website request that the user's machine 'shows' the certificate when entering the website. If certificates themselves are connected to specific domains, this is not something I'm know anything about.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that didn't clarify anything. I think the answer to your question has to be: You cannot detect the presence of a certificate that was issued for a domain you do not own.

Comment: Here’s an article how to implement authentication using client-side certificates in PHP, https://cweiske.de/tagebuch/ssl-client-certificates.htm - see if that helps.